# Extract data from deeply-nested JSON

Tags: python, arrays, json, dictionary

I am new to JSON data and I am trying to get down to a very deeply nested dictionary that sits inside of 3 arrays and a dictionary of a JSON file. I am trying to get to the dictionary with the label "player". I am trying to extract the players for all teams to then move into a DataFrame so I can use for other analysis.

How do i write loop to get to this data?

This is what I'm trying to do but it doesn't work:

```
rostered = json.dumps(rostered_players)
player_value = [[
                values['playerPoolEntry']['player']
                ]for values in rostered]
```

Here is a sample of data that I am working with:

```
rostered = 
'''[
  [    
    {
    "appliedStatTotal": 260.05,
    "entries": [
        [
            {
            "injuryStatus": "NORMAL",
            "lineupSlotId": 2,
            "playerId": 2977644,
            "playerPoolEntry": {
                                "appliedStatTotal": 37.6,
                                "id": 2977644,
                                "keeperValue": 56,
                                "keeperValueFuture": 56,
                                "lineupLocked": false,
                                "onTeamId": 1,
                                "player":   {
                                            "firstName": "Todd",
                                            "fullName": "Todd Gurley II",
                                            "id": 2977644,
                                            "injuryStatus": "ACTIVE",
                                            "lastName": "Gurley II"
                                            },
            "rosterLocked": false,
            "tradeLocked": false
                                }
                }
            ]
        ]
    }
],
    [
        {
            "appliedStatTotal": 260.05,
            "entries": [
            [
                {
                "injuryStatus": "NORMAL",
                "lineupSlotId": 4,
                "playerId": 3892889,
                "playerPoolEntry": {
                                "appliedStatTotal": 6.6000000000000005,
                                "id": 3892889,
                                "keeperValue": 5,
                                "keeperValueFuture": 5,
                                "lineupLocked": false,
                                "onTeamId": 2,
                                "player":   {
                                            "defaultPositionId": 3,
                                            "firstName": "Dede",
                                            "fullName": "Dede Westbrook",
                                            "id": 3892889,
                                            "lastName": "Westbrook"
                                            },
            "rosterLocked": false,
            "tradeLocked": false
                                    }
                    }
                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
]'''
```

Comment: aren't you supposed to use `json.loads` ?

Comment: dumps converts the string to a json object

Comment: @BenKowalsky no it doesn't. https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps

Answer (score -1):

One way to do this is to use recursion. This is a more functional approach.

```
from pprint import pprint

def iterate_deep(item):
  if isinstance(item, dict):
    for key, val in item.items():
      if key == 'player':
        pprint(val)
      else:
        iterate_deep(val)
  elif isinstance(item, list):
    for deeper_item in item:
      iterate_deep(deeper_item)

iterate_deep(rostered_players)
```

Comment: why would you use recursion for that? what if there are other `player` keys in other parts of the tree?

Comment: @njzk2 Because recursion is context-free. Obviously, there's nothing to stop him from using `iterate_deep` on that to go even deeper. But I don't know his intent. My function up there was only a demonstration of _one_ way to loop through the data.

Answer (score -1):

A possible solution could be parsing the given JSON as it is.

```
rostered=json.loads(rostered)
    player_values=[]
    for level0 in rostered:
        for level1 in level0:
            if 'entries' in level1:
                level2 = level1.get('entries')
                for level3 in level2:
                    for level4 in level3:
                        if 'playerPoolEntry' in level4 and 'player' in level4.get('playerPoolEntry'):
                            player_values.append(level4.get('playerPoolEntry').get('player'))
```

Comment: I tried this but it returned no values in the outputs

Comment: rostered=json.loads(rostered) add this line before running the loop. I've rectified the code.